# Screen flickering after update to 16.10 version

Tags: updates, screen, browser, 16.10

Screen started flickering after update from 16.04 to 16.10 version. It doesn't flicker until opening a browser and then cannot be stopped.

Comment: What GPU are you using? Are you using the proprietary drivers?

Comment: I have what might be a similar issue. Occasionally my second monitor will flash off, for about a second or two, and then come back on. It seems to be random (it just did it twice within 10 seconds, but might go many minutes without doing it). I have a "Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)"

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/838957/upgrade-to-16-10-causes-desktop-backlight-flickering/840192