# Weird red and blue bars/dots

Tags: 19.10, visual-artifacts

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10. Whenever I unlock my computer after closing the lid some weird red and blue dots/lines show up on the unlock screen background. After unlocking, Visual Studio Code keeps the same pattern in some parts. It's usually only the terminal and everything I type there, but it can also affect the minimap too.

Reopening it solves the issue, but I'm quite annoyed by this little bug. My system is up to date and I haven't done any serious modification to it. The language/code I'm working on doesn't seem to be related as it has been happening for some time.

[image]

Comment: If you have an Intel Graphics card, see whether this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207777/graphical-glitches-using-ubuntu-18-04-on-dell-xps-13-2019-laptop/1207788#1207788 helps. It involves adding a kernel parameter that disables some power saving feature of the card (which is causing the problem). You can test and undo if it does not work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.