# Dell xps screen warping

Tags: dell, 20.04, intel-graphics, screen, xps

My computer has started having black specks all across the screen and the whole screen will warp around. It's difficult to get a good screenshot of it, but I've attached an example.

I'm using a Dell XPS 13(intel graphics) and running Ubuntu 20.04

[image: Some warping, fairly minor compared to other warping it does, but it's what I could capture.]

Comment: did you instal ubuntul or did it come preinstalled? if the first is the case you might try `sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04`-- but to be honest it more looks like an hardware fault

Comment: I installed Ubuntu. I tried running what you suggested, but no dice.

Comment: I also just tried the solution from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207777/graphical-glitches-using-ubuntu-18-04-on-dell-xps-13-2019-laptop). That didn't work either. I'll contact Dell support and see what they say.

Comment: I decided to try out some other operating systems by putting them on a flash drive to see if they had the same issue. I tried Pop os, UbuntuDDE, Solus, and Fedora. The two Ubuntu-based OSes, Pop os and UbuntuDDE, had the same issue while the other two did not. However, Solus had another issue where it didn't recognize my laptop's wifi card. So, now I'm dual-booting Ubuntu and Fedora to see if Fedora works better. So far it seems more stable on my laptop.