# Graphic glitches occurring randomly on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, 20.04, visual-artifacts

I'm having graphics issues with my freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04. I've added a picture to show you the graphic glitches happening randomly. There is no clear pattern. It occurs very shortly (in a fraction of second), so it was quite hard to capture that picture.

[image: link to picture]

Graphic card details:

```
  *-display                 
   Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
   Produkt: UHD Graphics 620
   Hersteller: Intel Corporation
   Physische ID: 2
   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:02.0
   Logischer Name: /dev/fb0
   Version: 07
   Breite: 64 bits
   Takt: 33MHz
   Fähigkeiten: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   Konfiguration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
   Ressourcen: iomemory:1f0-1ef iomemory:1f0-1ef irq:129 memory:1ff2000000-1ff2ffffff memory:1fc0000000-1fcfffffff ioport:3000(Größe=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

the notebook being used is an YP EliteBook 840 G5. I didn't install any additional drivers.

Comment: Edit your answer and provide output of `sudo lshw -c display`: this will give information about your graphics card

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207777/graphical-glitches-using-ubuntu-18-04-on-dell-xps-13-2019-laptop/1207788#1207788 Please report back.

Comment: @vanadium wonderful, that actually did the job, thank you. 
For the record here: 
Adding i915.enable_psr=0 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=wasn't enough/not the one. 
i915.modset=0 and i915.enable_fbc=0 had to be there, so probably one of those.

Comment: OK, then I will mark your question as a duplicate.