# Graphic glitches occurring randomly on Ubuntu 20.04 (repost)

Tags: graphics, 20.04, intel-graphics, visual-artifacts

I'm having graphics issues with my freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04. I've added a picture to show you the graphic glitches happening randomly. There is no clear pattern. It occurs very shortly (in a fraction of second), so it was quite hard to capture that picture.

This question was already answered before, but the solution didn't work. The error came back.

Graphic card details:

```
  *-display                 
   Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
   Produkt: UHD Graphics 620
   Hersteller: Intel Corporation
   Physische ID: 2
   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:02.0
   Logischer Name: /dev/fb0
   Version: 07
   Breite: 64 bits
   Takt: 33MHz
   Fähigkeiten: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   Konfiguration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
   Ressourcen: iomemory:1f0-1ef iomemory:1f0-1ef irq:129 memory:1ff2000000-1ff2ffffff memory:1fc0000000-1fcfffffff ioport:3000(Größe=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

the notebook being used is an HP EliteBook 840 G5. I didn't install any additional drivers.

Output of dmidecode -s bios-version:

```
Q78 Ver. 01.03.00
```

output of free -h

```
              gesamt      belegt       frei     gemeinsam    Zwischen   verfügbar
Speicher:       7,4Gi       1,6Gi       3,8Gi       342Mi       2,0Gi       5,2Gi
Auslager:       975Mi          0B       975Mi
```

output of sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

output of grep -i swap /etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

output of sudo blkid | grep -i swap

```
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1: UUID="a87ef036-3178-4736-8db3-255fa03dce6b" TYPE="swap"
```

output of grep -i resume /etc/default/grub is empty.

output of grep -i GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

output of cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume: not found

output of swapon -s:

```
Dateiname               Typ     Größe   Benutzt Priorität
/dev/dm-2                               partition   999420  0   -2
```

I'm not able to repost the image, so please check here: [Graphic glitches occurring randomly on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254853/graphic-glitches-occurring-randomly-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Looks like a hardware problem. The LCD display, the display cable or its connection, or the motherboard. Try pressing on various areas on the LCD screen with your thumb and see if you can create the problem. Also see if opening/closing the lid causes the problem.

Comment: @heynnema I'm not able to reproduce it that way. It also has some patterns, that's why I think it might be kernel or driver related. It usually occurs when reading PDFs with standard PDF program of Ubuntu 20.04. Also to mention, this Notebook hasn't been used at all for a year, and that year before everything was fine with Windows. This installation of Ubuntu 20.04. is new and completetely fresh.

Comment: Show me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Also, see if my quick answer improves things at all. Report back.

Comment: I couldn't find a BIOS update on the hp.com web site, as I guess that BIOS updates are done directly in your current BIOS. Please enter your BIOS and check for a newer version there. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for the idea. I've updated my BIOS to the newest version, but the glitches stay.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Also, do you know how to boot with **nomodeset**? That might eliminate a graphic driver problem. Your screen resolution may be off during the test.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema done, see original question. I tried nomodeset, but suspend stops working, so generally not an option for me. But I can give it a try, use it for a few days and tell you if it helps solving the issue.

Comment: nomodeset is only for testing. Using it will only eliminate a graphic driver problem. nomodeset should have nothing to do with suspend... although your swap is WAY too small. Show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and I'll write an update to my answer to increase your swap.

Comment: @heynnema I've added the output to the question - seems to be the same as you added in your anwer. OK, I will test nomodeset again and let you know. Just needs some time as I never know when the gliches occur.

Comment: No, my swap is using a 4G /swapfile. Yours is currently using a too small swap partition.

Comment: @heynnema I tried the nomodeset again. Indeed I didn't have issues, but as I said, the suspend issue stays. Actually, this is a hint: I think that suspend causes the issue. Every time after a suspend, the glitches are starting to occur. I'm not 100% sure of that yet, but I will observe that in the next days if it's really related to that.

Comment: To add to that: suspend causes me issues anyway. the time to resume the notebook takes very long, something like >30 secs sometimes.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid | grep -i swap` and `grep -i resume /etc/default/grub` and `grep -i GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX /etc/default/grub` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and `swapon -s`.

Comment: @heynnema done.

Comment: Thanks for the command outputs. Yes, it confirms that you're currently using a 1G swap partition. Go ahead and try and create a 4G /swapfile. Remember to comment out "/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0" and add my /swapfile line.