# Dell XP3 9310 with Intel Iris Xe Graphics (i5/i7) - Flickering screen on boot-up

Tags: boot, display, dell, xps

I bought a Dell XPS 13 9310 with the 11th generation i7 processor, Intel(R) Iris Xe Graphics, and preinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 (Kernel 5.6.0.1022-oem). After installing the suggested updates, I restarted the laptop and it has been restarted with flickering/tearing (horizontal lines) on the boot-up process and I cannot see and do anything. Then it goes into GNU GRUB options.
I restored the system into the original configuration and have updated firmware to the last version (Ver. 1.1.1) and after installing the updates, I have still the issue.
I have tried Ubuntu 18.04 and after installing updates the issue came back!!!
[See the flickering display photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f550c.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graphical glitches using Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell XPS 13 2019 laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207777/graphical-glitches-using-ubuntu-18-04-on-dell-xps-13-2019-laptop)

Comment: I have applied all the proposed solutions that I found on the net including:

1) Modifying gedit~/.config/monitors.xml with lower refresh rate and even screen size.
2) Adding 20-intel.conf into /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d, defining Intel Graphics device.
3) Choosing "Ubuntu on Wayland" method.
4) Applying sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-video-intel.

Unfortunately, none of them worked!

Comment: I do not see the trick in the post of which I marked this as duplicate. There is a significant chance that that will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium, for your comment. Although I had tested this solution, I tried it again by 1) Updating the grub by using sudo vi /etc/default/grub, 2) replacing the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash”
with the following line 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0”
2) save the file and executing sudo update-grub, and finally 3) reboot.

Unfortunately, the issue still exists. I will return the product to DELL or install MS Windows. I hope MS Windows works.

Comment: I retracted my duplicate flag: you indeed tested this correctly. MS Windows for sure will work. Since you purchased the laptop with Ubuntu, you will have support. I once returned a newly purchased Dell and they replaced the motherboard. So a specific issue with this machine is always possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this issue is to do with the intel microcode - see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=260710

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, while this link may answer the question, it's better to include essential parts here.