# Graphical glitching in 22.04 - ThinkPad X270

Tags: graphics, screen, thinkpad, 22.04, tearing

After installing 22.04 on my ThinkPad X270, I am experiencing numerous screen glitches which I have never seen on 20.04.

It looks somewhat like what you would see on an old TV before slapping it a few times and it fixing itself (some kind of de-syncing or something). The image on the screen seems to slide away and glitch back to position quickly repeatedly for 1-3 sec, then it stops and it is OK.

X270 specs:

```
Intel® Core™ i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
16,0 GiB RAM
```

This is just one of several issues I am facing after installing 22.04 which were not present in older versions. Overall I like 22.04, but so far the experience feels a little unpolished, as if this was some obscure distro, not Ubuntu:

- not detecting power cord connect/disconnect
- unable to wake up from suspension in low battery state
- sometimes unable to open right top corner menu in lock screen

Sometimes I am thinking about downgrading back to 20.04

Comment: Perhaps this may help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1207788/558158

Comment: that seems to be a very different thing

Comment: Still it was worth checking it, I guess, unless you do not appreciate hints like this. That was actually an issue I had myself.

Comment: Well, I actually have not seen this glitch since trying your tip. 
Any idea why this could begin with upgrading to Ubutnu 22?
Also maybe consider adding an answer so I can accept it